# Galaxy S3 Bug: Navigation app crashes when clicking "Start"

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, crashes, bugs, google-maps-navigation, navigation

Summary: Route navigation crashes on starting of route finding.

This is an intermittent bug. It only started happening recently - I think it coincides with when on a desktop browser I volunteered to start using the new version of Google Maps. (I wanted to use the new traffic monitoring feature). I didn't realise it would propagate my choices to my phone as well.

Is there any fix? E.g.

- How can I configure the navigation app on my phone to use only the more stable mainstream navigation app?
- How can I configure my Google account to revert to the mainstream version of Google Maps, for all devices?
- Are there any third party apps which have route navigation similar in quality to that of Google's?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you enter the starting point and destination, the app gives you the possible routes. On that screen the best route has a start navigation option; selecting this causes the app to crash. Instead select the route you prefer and then hit the start arrow at the bottom right corner. Works for me.